# Multi step form - Uncaught TypeError and the form is only submited with "novalidate" property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I created a multi step form using bootstrap and jquery.

When I click in some button to go to the next step it appears this error on the console:

```
tab.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
    at t.a._activate (tab.js:155)
    at t.a.show (tab.js:120)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (tab.js:249)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.t._jQueryInterface [as tab] (tab.js:236)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (tab.js:266)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Other issue is that when the submit button "Store" is clicked the form is not submitted, only is submited if I add to the element `<form>` this: "novalidate", like `<form method="post" action=".." novalidate>`. Without this property it appears always the error: "An invalid form control with name='conference_name' is not focusable." on the required fields.

Do you know where is the issue?

I have the html below for the multi step form:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')

  <div class="container nopadding py-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="h5">Create Conference</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12">

        <div class="registration_form">

          <ul class="nav nav-pills bg-light-gray registration_form_list" role="tablist">
            <li class="">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                Step 1<br><small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">General Info</small></a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                Step 2<br><small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Conference Creator info</small></a>
            </li>
            <li class="disabled">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
                Step 3<br><small class="d-none d-md-inline-block">Registration Types</small></a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <form method="post" name="test" class="clearfix" action="/conference/store"  novalidate >
            <div class="tab-content registration_body bg-white" id="myTabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="conference_name" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Conference Name</label>
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="conference_name" id="conference_name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label for="categories" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Categories</label>
                    <select id="tag_list" required multiple class="form-control" name="categories" id="categories">
                      <option>1</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- more form-group... -->
                <div class="float-right">
                  <button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                          class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">
                    Go to Setp 2
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="step2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="conference_creator_description" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Description</label>
                  <textarea required name="conference_creator_description" id="conference_creator_description" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <!-- more form-group... --> 

                <button type="button" href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                        class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-primary btn prev-step">
                  Go Back to Step 1
                </button>
                <button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                        class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">
                  Go to Step 2
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="step3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="registration_type_name" class="text-heading h6 font-weight-semi-bold">Registration type name</label>
                  <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="registration_type_name" id="registration_type_name">
                </div>

                <!-- more form-group... -->

                <button type="button" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"
                        class="btn mr-2 btn-outline-primary btn prev-step">
                  Go Back To Step 2
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn">Store</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Then the JS for the navigation between the multi step form steps:

```
@section('scripts.footer')

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('a.nav-link').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        $(".next-step").click(function (e) {
            var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
            $active.parent().next().removeClass('disabled');
            nextTab($active);
        });

        $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {
            var $active = $('.nav-pills li a.active');
            prevTab($active);
        });

        function nextTab(elem) {
            $(elem).parent().next().find('a.nav-link').click();
        }
        function prevTab(elem) {
            $(elem).parent().prev().find('a.nav-link').click();
        }
    });


</script>

@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using buttons to navigate your multistep form you need to use `a` tag, because button doesn't have an `href` attribute and isn't responsible for that kind of job you are looking for, even on their [official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs) you can see they are using `a` instead of `button`:

```
<!-- more form-group... -->
<div class="float-right">
     ....
     <a href="#step-2" aria-controls="step-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="btn mr-2 btn-primary btn next-step">Home</a>
     ....
 </div>
```

Use this instead of your `button` elements just change the links, classes and if you want `aria-control` for other steps and you should be fine traversing your steps

Comment: Thanks but the uncaught type error still appears when the navigation links are clicked. Also, the form is not submitted, only with the "novalidate" property.

Comment: instead of `return false` try `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks, but the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data-target` also if you want to use `button`. and use `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` to avoid the type error

```
    <!-- more form-group... -->
```

```js
$(function(){

//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
 
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    background: #6441A5; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #6441A5, #2a0845); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
    background: transparent;
}

/*form styles*/
#msform {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: relative;
}

/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}

/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#msform input:focus, #msform textarea:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #ee0979;
    outline-width: 0;
    transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease-in;
}

/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #ee0979;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #ee0979;
}

#msform .action-button-previous {
    width: 100px;
    background: #C5C5F1;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button-previous:hover, #msform .action-button-previous:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #C5C5F1;
}

/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 26px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
}

/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none;
}

/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before, #progressbar li.active:after {
    background: #ee0979;
    color: white;
}


/* Not relevant to this form */
.dme_link {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.dme_link a {
    background: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ee0979;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.dme_link a:hover, .dme_link a:focus {
    background: #C5C5F1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form id="msform">
            <!-- progressbar -->
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
                <li>Social Profiles</li>
                <li>Account Setup</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- fieldsets -->
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Tell us something more about you</h3>
                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
                <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
                <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter"/>
                <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook"/>
                <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus"/>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
                <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Fill in your credentials</h3>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the js in the question disable the capacity of user select the tabs and just allow the user to navigate between tabs with the buttons that have the .prev-step and .next-step classes. With your code its possible to select the tabs and there are no buttons to navigate between the steps, so it seems that its not for a multi step form.